# Azure Webjob System.IO.PathTooLongException

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, pathtoolongexception

I'm trying to deploy an On Demand node.js WebJob on my Azure Website that uses a few node libraries, but every run generates the error

```
Failed to copy job files: System.IO.PathTooLongException: The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
```

Taking out the libraries remedies the error, but then I can't run the WebJob. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently a known limitation with WebJobs/node.js/Windows.

Since the WebJob is running from the temporary directory (which has an already long path start) and node_modules in some cases tend to have long dependancy tree which concludes with files that have a long path and windows limitation of the path length.

Workarounds:

1. Remove files with the longest paths, usually they are test related and will not affect your script.
2. If you use npm install you can try using npm dedupe which can help (https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-dedupe.html).

Comment: Is there a way to figure out which files are causing the issue? Perhaps a recursive file iteration with fs?

Comment: I use dir /s /b and go for the longest

Comment: I'm also getting this, but in my case the job's status stays "starting" indefinitely (it's been a couple of days now) and the delete button is grayed out...